# how to know which exact implementation of interface EntityManager is used at run?

Tags: java, implementation, entitymanager

i have a service like that

```
 @Service
 public class AuditService {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager            entityManager;

    public void save(final Audit audit) {
    entityManager.persist(audit);
  }

}
```

I just want to know which exact implementation of EntityManager is used. The purpose is to find it, in order to get the code of persist method()

Comment: If the code in the question is code that you can modify, simply add this line (to method `save()`): `System.out.println(entityManager.getClass());`

Comment: @Abra ok but it returns to me : class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110. so i can' t know the real implementation class.